# Query in mongodb within two joined collections

Tags: database, mongodb

If I have a collection of employees and a collection of their salaries. How can i find the employee with highest salary and lowest?

```
Employee:{
{id:123, 
name:abc},
{id:456, 
name:efg}
}

Salary:{
{id:123, 
amount:100},
{id:456, 
amount:200}
}
```

Currently I am using node js and mongooses in my project.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What should happen if more than one employee shares the highest or lowest salary?  The data model seems rather strange ... isn't it likely that more than one employee shares the same salary?  If so, doesn't the current data model require that duplicate entries be made in the `Salary` collection?

Comment: I just have this random scenario for learning purpose. I'm novice in noSQL. I have seen aggregation, lookup but not quite clear about it. So I thought a particular example will help me out to understand better.

Comment: A good place to start might be trying the [`"$lookup"` examples from the online manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#examples).  You can see the first example on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4SsmaPcWGVw).